# on submit form get trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

In js, I need to use :

```
$('.grid').on('submit','form', function (ev) {}
```

because i need to validate a html5 element into the form.

My problem is:

I have  2 submit button with 2 kind of "data". I need to get the trigger for using:

```
 if(typeof [trigger].data('save') != 'undefined'){
 }
```

it is the part of my current JS:

```
$('.grid').on('submit','form', function (ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
console.log(typeof $(this).data('save') );
if(typeof $(this).data('save') != 'undefined' && jQuery("form")[0].checkValidity()){
          // do something
    }
});
```

$(this) refere to the form element.
I need that find the submit triggered button (not twice and not other submit button)

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$(ev.target).data('save')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [**event.target**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

> The DOM element that initiated the event.

Change code to

```
 if(typeof $(ev.target).data('save') != 'undefined'){
 }
```